# Looking for the definition of 'locally finite-dimensional'

Tags: ring-theory, division-algebras

Recently, reading the book '[Skew Linear Groups](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=SU84AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=locally%20finite-dimensional%20over%20its%20centre&source=bl&ots=y3dgi0OXB0&sig=BzYK_Prr0MMt1HkSi-fpy6W_W8A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yj0SUb2VBYbV4gTS5oHwBQ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=locally%20finite-dimensional%20over%20its%20centre&f=false)' by M. Shirvani and B. A. F. Wehrfritz, I've encountered the following:

```
Let D be a division ring which is locally finite-dimensional over 
its centre but not finite dimensional over its centre.
```

Searching the web, I could not find the definition of being locally finite-dimensional.
The 'usual candidates' for a local property in rings are things to do with ideals, but as there are no non-trivial ideals in a division ring, the only thing that sounds remotely close is looking at finitely generated sub-algebras (when looking at $D$ as an algebra over it's centre) - is that correct? Can anyone point me to the definition of this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps related to *local* subrings of $D$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An algebra of any kind (Lie, associative, etc.) is locally finite-dimensional (also called locally finite) if every finitely generated subalgebra is finite dimensional over the ground field. See [this](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Locally_finite_algebra).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't another way to view this be:

D is a module over its center Z,
and every element $d \in D$ is contained in a finitely-generated submodule of D viewed in this way, though D itself is not finitely generated as a module over Z.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, a ``locally finite dimensional" representation $V$ of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is one for which $U(\mathfrak{g}) v$ is finite dimensional for every $v \in V$.  Thus, perhaps in your case you should require $Z d$ to be finite-dimensional for every $d \in D$ where $Z$ is the center.